Forging Process Simulation with Forge NxT
I'm currently working on a project simulating the forging process of a screw using Forge NxT. My thermal model involves a two-step approach:
1.Forging Cycle Simulation:

Waiting Time: This step simulates the heated screw placed on the lower die before the forging begins.
Forging: The temperature of the dies changes due to heat transfer and friction with the screw during this stage.

2.Thermal Cycle Simulation: This step uses the thermal conditions obtained from the forging cycle simulation.
I'm encountering some challenges:

Insufficient Heat Transfer at Screw-Die Interface: The current model suggests less heat transfer than expected between the screw and the die.
High Temperature Gradient in Upper Die: The simulation shows a significant temperature difference within the upper die, suggesting potential conductivity limitations.
Neglecting Radiative Heat Transfer: Forge Nxt doesn't seem to consider radiative heat transfer from the hot screw.
Premature Steady-State: The simulation reaches a steady-state temperature too quickly (within tens of cycles) compared to the expected hundreds of cycles in real-world forging.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to address these issues and improve the accuracy of my thermal model.
Thanks,
Lower Die Heating Profile: I expect a more realistic temperature profile for the lower die holding the screw.
Upper Die Heating Due to Radiation: I expect the upper die to absorb some heat from the hot screw due to radiation during the waiting time.
Uniform Heat Distribution in Upper Die: I expect a more uniform temperature distribution within the upper die.
Time to Reach Steady State: I expect the model to reach steady state after around 600 cycles, not 30.
